# Eloquent all and custom property

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

Let's say, I have an Order model and I have an endpoint, which querys all the orders.

Now it's something like this:

```
public function findAll(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
    {
        return Order::all()->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

But, I want to add custom properties to the json response.

My order looks like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'productIds',
        'fullname',
        'phone',
        'location'
    ];
```

And I want to add a 'names' and a 'totalPrice' property, which are not in the DB, they are calculated by a getProductNameList() and a getSumPrice() method. How is that possible? :)

Comment: Are you using Slim and Eloquent?  This is usually the use case for transformers.

Comment: Never heard of transformers. :D

Comment: Transformers have the responsibility of standardizing the output for resources.  You could implement this yourself using collection or array mapping.

Comment: Yea, array mapping looks like a solution. Thanks man, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Do you know about Eloquent Accessors/Mutators? And did you read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json ?

Comment: Wow. That helped a lot, maybe that's the best solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add the data directly from the model using the `$append` model attribute like this:

```
Class Order extends Model
{
    protected $append = ['attribute_name'];

    public function getAttributeName() {
        $dataToReturn = [];
        return ($dataToReturn);
    }
}
```

Doc here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Answer (score 0):

you can use json response so you can pass custom array

```
    public function findAll(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
    {
            $order= Order::all();
       return response()->json([
            'order' =>   $order,
            'names' => 'CA',
           'totalPrice'=>150
        ]);
        }
```

As per your question you are using separate methods for calculating so `getProductNameList()` and a `getSumPrice()` .In both method you can return $value and method response you can pass it to this array
For more ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses

Comment: Seems fine, but is there any solution to add that property inside the order object and not next to it?

Comment: ya .you can create an array and pass it in single array

Comment: Since this is tagged `slim`, not `laravel`,  I don't think this will be valid.

Comment: Meh, it won't work, since Order:all() gives back an array of orders, and I want to add the totalPrice and names to every single order object.